# Edit Microsoft Word .doc and .docx files

Tags: ruby, ms-word

I would like to translate all the text inside a Microsoft Word .doc or .docx file without changing the formatting of the file itself.

Are there any gems or libraries that can help me with this?

Answer (score 2):

The general case is extremely complicated, but for translating continuous runs of text that are formatted the same, you can use [WIN32OLE](https://ruby-doc.org/stdlib-2.5.1/libdoc/win32ole/rdoc/WIN32OLE.html) to access Word documents using Word so long as you are on Windows and have a copy of Word installed.

You can find documentation on [Word's object model](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/api/overview/word/object-model). You can also use the built-in *Object Browser* (start the macro editor and press <kbd>F2</kbd>).

The following short script can form the starting point for your exploration:

```
require 'win32ole'

file = ENV['USERPROFILE'] + '/Desktop/' + 'This is a test.docx';

word = WIN32OLE.new('Word.Application')
word.visible = true

doc = word.Documents.Open(file)

doc.paragraphs.each { |p| puts p.Range.Text }

doc.Close()

word.Quit()
```

Comment: Thanks, I will look into this. Unfortunately, I am on a mac, and more importantly Heroku servers won't have the library either.